# Too reload or too update: SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, single-page-application

In a single page application, when you post some data to the server to either create or update a record in database. Which method is prefer after a success (200) response? Perform a `window.location.reload()` to rebuild the table grid? Or return a newly or updated data to push back in the component model?

I understand it mainly a preference. Just curious which is perceive better.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions based entirely on opinions or preferences are strictly off topic here, because it would be impossible for there to be a single "correct" answer.  Instead of asking what people prefer, it would be better for you to ask about specific problems you are having with the tactic you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

> return a newly or updated data to push back in the component model

I do this.
If you want to make real time web apps I think you have to use [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) or something similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really building a SPA, `window.location.reload()` is out of the panorama, reloading is relevant in a Traditional webpage Lifecycle, not in SPA's